# The width 100% why not full width and how to?

Tags: html, css

I'm sorry, I speak a little English.

The HTML (with CSS):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #content {
                width: 1920px;
                background-color: blue;
            }
            #footer {
                width: 100%;
                background-color: pink;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">foo</div>
        <div id="footer">bar</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Screenshot:

https://i.imgur.com/PDedGgm.png

My screen size is 1366 pixel. The #content div width: 1920px. The #footer div width why only 1366 px? I would like full width, real 100%.

If possible, I would like to keep this layout:

```
<body>
    <div id="content">foo</div>
    <div id="footer">bar</div>
</body>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by **real 100%**? State a figure.

Answer (score 2):

Yes that's completely normal.

The 100% will take the whole width of the page. At the 1920px it just keeps going because the screen is probably too small for the div. If you want both to take the whole width of the page then you have to use 100% instead of 1920px. You can see in your screenshot that you scrolled to the middle of the page. If you make both 100% then it should look like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #content {
                width: 100%;
                background-color: blue;
            }
            #footer {
                width: 100%;
                background-color: pink;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">foo</div>
        <div id="footer">bar</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And also add this to your CSS. It will remove the padding and the margin on the website:

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

---

## Both to 1920px

And if you want to make both to 1920px than you can add `width: 1920px` to your body and make the `#content` and `#footer` to `width: 100%;`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
              width: 1920px;
            }
        
            #content {
                width: 100%;
                background-color: blue;
            }
            #footer {
                width: 100%;
                background-color: pink;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">foo</div>
        <div id="footer">bar</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the footer is 100% of it's containing element body which is the viewable part of the page

Answer (score 0):

You used absolute width in px for #content. If #footer would be a direct child of #content it would also have the width of 1920px. But because it is a direct child of the body it has the width of the screen size when you use a width of 100%.

You could wrap both with a #wrapper with the width of 1920px. And it is not neccessary to set a width of 100% for child div. They will have 100% width of the parent by default.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #wrapper {
                width: 1920px;
            }

           /*  #footer, #content {
                width: 100%;
            } */

            #content {
                background-color: blue;
            }

            #footer {
                background-color: pink;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="content">foo</div>
            <div id="footer">bar</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could've also taken the body